# Realm browser is asking me to update file even though compiled with Realm 2.5

Tags: realm

I have downloaded and compiled the latest and greatest version of Realm Cocoa which is 2.5. However each time that I open the Realm Browser its telling me that my file format is out of date. Is there a flag that must be set to use the new features?

I am using Carthage as my dependency manager.

Comment: Which version of the Realm Browser are you using?

Comment: It's version Version 2.1.7 (91) from the AppStore.

Comment: Realm Cocoa v2.5.0 and Realm Browser v2.1.7 both work the same file format. Can you share the exact message you're seeing in Realm Browser?

Comment: The exact message is "default.realm is at an older file format version and must be upgraded before it can be opened. Would you like to proceed.."

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the file you're opening was created with Realm Cocoa v2.5.0? I just tested with a simple app using Realm Objective-C v2.5.0 and confirmed that Realm Browser opens the newly-created file without warning. Opening a file created by an earlier version of Realm Objective-C (i.e., v2.4.4) does trigger the dialog you mention.

Comment: What about realm-swift?

Comment: The behavior is the same: files created by v2.5.0 are opened by Browser v2.1.7 without message, while files created by prior versions display the prompt you mention.

Comment: This has to do with Carthage.. I think I have something set weird. Completely user error..

Comment: I'm glad to hear you've worked out what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Downloading version **[2.1.1](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/v2.1.1)** fixed the issue for me.